# function that calculates non-zero inputs of a vector

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm new to scheme and having difficulty understanding vectors in scheme. I need to create a function that calculates the number of non-zero inputs in
a vector. I need to do this by not converting the vector into a list.
For exampl3.

```
(non-zero-dim #(3 0 2 4 0 2))
returns 4
```

My code so far is

```
(define non-zero-input
(lambda (vector)
(let ((size (vector-length vector)))
  do ((position 0 (+ position 1))
      (total 0
(if ((not (zero? vector-ref vector position)))
(+ total 1))
(((= position size) total)))))))
```

However I'm getting this error `:do: bad syntax in: (do ((position 0 (+ position 1)) (total 0 (if ((not (zero? vector-ref vector position))) (+ total 1)) (((= position size) total))`
How do i fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in procedures [`vector-length`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html?q=vector-length#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._vector-length%29%29) and [`vector-filter-not`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html?q=vector-filter-not#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fvector..rkt%29._vector-filter-not%29%29), you can simplify your function as:

```
(define (non-zero-dim vec)
  (vector-length (vector-filter-not zero? vec)))
```

For example,

```
> (non-zero-dim #(3 0 2 4 0 2))
4
```

---

Some things to consider:

- Keep track of your brackets. For example, `(zero? vector-ref vector position)` should be `(zero? (vector-ref vector position))`, whereby arity of `zero?` is one, and arity of `vector-ref` is two. Similarly with `do ...` vs. `(do ...` etc.
- `if` statements **must** have an *else* clause (ie. `(if condition then else)`). For example, `(if true 1)` would fail, but `(if true 1 2)` would pass. Hence, `(if ((not (zero? vector-ref vector position))) (+ total 1))` would fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `racket/vector` package has [`vector-count`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fvector..rkt%29._vector-count%29%29), which returns the number of elements of a vector that satisfy a given predicate. This makes counting the non-zero values trivial:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(require racket/function racket/vector)

(define (non-zero-dim vec)
  (vector-count (negate zero?) vec))

(println (non-zero-dim #(3 0 2 4 0 2)) ; 4
```